# Общение C# и Java

Tags: java, c#, c++, jni

Встал небольшой вопрос по обращению к Java из C#. Конкретно интересует как толкнуть JVM из под C#, да и обращения из шурупа в джава. По поводу Java -> C# нашёл небольшую статейку на Хабре ([тыц](https://habrahabr.ru/post/92924/)), но вот по поводу обращений из под C# к Java коду откровенно ничего не понял. хД

Там же, на Хабре, нашёл статью по обращению к Java из крестов ([тыц](https://habrahabr.ru/post/258707/)) и статья довольно интересна (ибо подразумевает под собой создание "glue" библиотеки, да). Но, чего нигде не нашёл (может плохо искал, конечно), это как в C# используя тот же JNI (или нет, я просто не в курсе других методов) запустить JVM и отправить программу написанную на Java на отработку. Плюс, понятное дело, во время работы кода мне нужно как-то взаимодействовать с ним из кода на C# (вообще в обще стороны C# <-> Java).

Подкиньте, пожалуйста, статей по этому поводу. В идеале - пошаговую инструкцию. Совсем в идеале - с разъяснениями по каждому шагу. Заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: В C# используется Pinvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой проект [IKVM](http://IKVM.net) - реализация JVM на .NET. Оно умеет динамически подключать `.jar` файлы, либо перекомпилировать `.jar` в .NET сборки (`.dll`)

Команда для перекомпиляции `.jar` в `.dll`:

> ikvmc -target:library mylib.jar

Answer (score 3):

Любая удобная форма [межпроцессного взаимодействия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Не совсем то, что я искал, так как меня скорее интересует сознание "монолитной" программы с подключением нескольких языков и организацией их общения через native, нежели запуск нескольких программ и организация их общения в этой "любой удобной форме". Но, в целом это тоже нужно, благодарю.

Comment: @NetScum Монолитной программы у вас не получится, как минимум потому, что приложения должны хоститься на своих виртуальных машинах (два различных процесса). Хотя, вы можете погуглить имплементации Java on CLR, и писать/вызывать сборки в рамках CLS, но игра вряд ли будет стоить свеч.

Comment: @NetScum Можно опуститься до COM. С сишарпом проблем не будет, а вот Java... Ну и о кроссплатформенности речи не будет.

Comment: @free_ze все получится.